# User/Group access on comsos db account

Tags: azure, azure-cosmosdb

Can we give only particular access to the user/group in cosmos db ?

Ex: 1. reader, execute, update firewall access to a user
2. read + write access, make changes to db, update firewall to another user
3. deny access to add or remove dbs or containers or deny to update

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 1):

Apart from the System [Built in Roles](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/role-based-access-control#built-in-roles), you can create Custom roles for your requirement, here is the documentation on the [same](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/role-based-access-control/custom-roles#custom-role-example).

Note : There are certain role [limits](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/role-based-access-control/custom-roles#custom-role-limits) .

Comment: How can we create custom role for update/deny firewall on a user ??